# CAShapeLayer doesn't rotate with CGAffineTransformRotate on devices older than iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform, cashapelayer

I'm creating simple Arc type chart like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


CGFloat lineWidth = 18.5f;
CGFloat margin = 11;
CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
                       CGRectMake(margin + lineWidth/2,
                                  margin + lineWidth/2,
                                  CGRectGetWidth(rect) - margin * 2 - lineWidth,
                                  CGRectGetWidth(rect)- margin * 2 - lineWidth)
                       ] CGPath]];
[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[_fillColor CGColor]];
[circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[circleLayer setLineWidth:18.5f];
[circleLayer setLineCap:kCALineCapRound];
[circleLayer setStrokeEnd: _fill];
CGPathRef path = createPathRotatedAroundBoundingBoxCenter(circleLayer.path, -1.5707965);
circleLayer.path  = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
[[self layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

And below is function used for making rotation, so that the 0 points north.

```
static CGPathRef createPathRotatedAroundBoundingBoxCenter(CGPathRef path, CGFloat radians) {

CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, radians);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);
return CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(path, &transform);
}
```

Now tricky part:

Why is that only works on devices (5s, 6) and simulators (tested on range of simulated devices with iOS from 8.3 to 9.3 ) starting from iPhone 5s.

[expected result on newer devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIEsG.png)

On earlier devices it fails

[Failed rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGAeZ.png)

The only workaround I found is use:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.5707965);
```

on containing UIView

Comment: this code is not working in iphone 4s device ya simulator

Comment: It's strange, cause it was copied straight from Xcode project...